# JLPT N1 listening question: Confused about sequence of events

Tags: jlpt, time, listening

There is a JLPT N1 listening practice question from a third-party website, and I believe its answer is incorrect, but want to make sure. The script is copied below.

> 農園で男の人が農業体験の参加者に話しています。参加者はこの後すぐ何をしますか。
>
> 男：おはようございます。今日の一日農業体験のスケジュールについてご説明します。ええ、皆さんに事前に配布しました案内では、午前中に畑で野菜の収穫、午後から牛の世話となっていました。それがですね、準備の都合で、午前と午後の作業を入れ替えて実質いたします。ええ、午前の作業が終わったら、この土地の名産や採りたての新鮮な野菜を使った料理を、地元農家の若手グループと一緒に作りたいと思います。昼食時には、彼らの最近の取り組みについて話を聞いていただければと思います。今日一日、よろしくお願いします。
>
> 参加者はこの後すぐ何をしますか。
>
> 1．野菜を収穫する
>   2．牛の世話をする
>   3．食事の準備をする
>   4．若手グループの話を聞く
>
> 正しい答えは2 です。

(source: https://japanesetest4you.com/japanese-language-proficiency-test-jlpt-n1-listening-exercise-1/#more-244)

I don't understand how the answer is not 1.  If the 参加者 must immediately (この後すぐ) do 牛の世話をする, that would imply it is the afternoon (as described: 午後から牛の世話となっていました). However, the speaker begins with おはようございます, and speaks of a future task after the morning tasks are completed (午前の作業が終わったら...), implying that the morning tasks (野菜を収穫する) are not completed yet. Which would mean those are the first order of business for the 参加者.

Am I correct in my understanding and choice 1 is correct, or am I completely missing some crucial details here?

Comment: Is 実質 a typo for something else (e.g., 実施) here?

Comment: @Darius Jahandarie  You are probably correct, based on the audio and context.  But I copied the script exactly as is, so it's a typo on the website's part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You skipped the sentence 「それがですね、準備の都合で、午前と午後の作業を入れ替えて実施(×実質)いたします。」.

In this sentence, man tells attendances to switch work of morning and work of afternoon because of his preparation .

Comment: The typo of 実施 vs 実質 completely threw me off.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is 2.

The key sentence is

> それがですね、準備の都合で、午前と午後の作業を入れ替えて実施いたします。

which means that the ordering of 畑で野菜の収穫 (initially scheduled for the morning) and 牛の世話 (initially scheduled for the afternoon) are now swapped. So the morning task is now 牛の世話.